# How to replace WordPress sidebars (widget areas) with Gutenberg

Tags: templates, sidebar, block-editor

I'm trying to build my first Gutenberg theme, and I want to build a page template with the layout as shown below:

[image: template wireframe]

Pre-Gutenberg I would have built widget areas into the page template to create the layout. i.e. widget areas for the sidebar, and widget area 1 + 2.

I'm trying to do this now with *blocks*, and **I want to know what correct approach or best practise is for replacing widget areas in Gutenberg when developing themes**, could this be achieved with *InnerBlocks*, or *NestedBlocks*? Or some other means? Can anyone point me to examples?

Comment: Problem is right now Gutenberg is only available in the content area through the editor. [Phase 2](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13113) will include widgets as blocks.

Comment: @Alvaro any ideas when phase 2 will arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Alvaro said, You should start building blocks for widget areas. Once Phase 2 hit the core you can just simply show the blocks in other areas. Don't bother developing for Pre-Gutenberg widgets, You will double your work load.

Comment: Are you saying to build blocks instead of widgets now, if so how can these be used in widget areas?

Comment: Yes, Eventually The whole website will have block areas instead widget areas. So, you are making yourself full proof. And within this year, Once Phase 2 completes. Widget areas will be replaced with block areas.